# Get information in mail.php that is parsed into manage.html from function.js

Tags: php, javascript, html, email

You select the product in home.html
then cookies and functions in JS will parse the information into manage.html
then in manage.html you can fill in your information and send it to mail.php
then mail.php will look if the customer is already in the database, if not it will add.
then it will add the order into the database.

Everything else works, only the last step of adding the order to the database will not work, because I don't know how to get the JS in manage.html to mail.php.

I'm trying to use something like $_GET["something"]; in mail.php, 
to get information from JavaScript that is parsed into manage.html.

code in COOKIES.JS

```
function readCookies(name){
    var nameCookie = name + "=";
    var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i=0; i < cookieArray.length; i++){
        var thisCookie = cookieArray[i]
        while (thisCookie.charAt(0) ==' '){
            thisCookie = thisCookie.substring(1,thisCookie.length);
        }
        if (thisCookie.indexOf(nameCookie) == 0){
            return thisCookie.substring(nameCookie.length,thisCookie.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Code in FUNCTION.JS:

```
function cartShow(){
    NumberOrdered = 0;
    NumberOrdered = readCookies("NumberOrdered");
    tableRow = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= NumberOrdered; i++){
        NewOrder = "Order" + i;
        thisCookie = readCookies(NewOrder);
        fields = new Array();
        fields = thisCookie.split("|");
        tableRow += "<tr>"
            + "<td>" + fields[0] + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + fields[1] + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + fields[2] + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + fields[3] + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + fields[4] + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + fields[3] * fields[4] + "</td>"
            + "<td>" + "<img src=\"includes/images/delete.png\"/ OnClick=\"DeleteItem(" + i + ")\">" + "</td>"
            + "</tr>";
    }
    document.write(tableRow);
}

    function fillInForm(){

    NumberOrdered = 0;
    NumberOrdered = readCookies("NumberOrdered");

    for (i = 1; i <= NumberOrdered; i++){
        NewOrder = "Order" + i;
        thisCookie = "";
        thisCookie = readCookies(NewOrder);;
        fields = new Array();
        fields = thisCookie.split("|");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Product ID " + "&nbsp;" + i + "\" value=\"" + "&nbsp;" + fields[0] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Brand " + "&nbsp;" + i + "\" value=\"" + "&nbsp;" + fields[1] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Model " + "&nbsp;" + i + "\" value=\"" + "&nbsp;" + fields[2] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Price " + "&nbsp;" + i + "\" value=\"" + "&nbsp;" + fields[3] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Amount products " + "&nbsp;" + i + "\" value=\"" + "&nbsp;" + fields[4] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\"Total cost " + "&nbsp;" + i + "\" value=\"" + "&nbsp;" + fields[3] * fields[4] + "\">");
        document.write("<input type=hidden name=\" " + "\" value=\"" + "\">");

    }
}
```

This then is used to show some product information on MANAGE.HTML:

```
<form action="mail.php" enctype="text/plain" onSubmit="return checkForm(this);" method="get">
            <table border=1 summary="">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b><p name="id"> id</p></b></td>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b> brand</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b> model</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b> price</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b> number</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b> total</b></td>
                    <td bgcolor=#cccccc><b> delete</b></td>
                </tr>
                <script>
                    cartShow();
                    fillInForm();
                </script>
            </table>
<input type="image" src="includes/images/checkout.png" alt="" value="send" />
            </form>
```

After this, I need to get the information in MAIL.PHP.

Because `<script>cartShow(); fillInForm();</script>` in manage.html is showing the information in the table, I don't know how I can get it into MAIL.PHP.

I hope someone can help me out, I'm trying for the last 5 hours to figure this out.

Comment: If you dump the values in $_GET after submitting the form, what does/does not appear?

Comment: Well, the information that the customer needs to fill in the form in manage.html can be send to mail.php. But the order that is shown using javascript does not work. I don't know where to put the name="something". Because the name"something" in function.js will show up in manage.html but will not automatically be send to mail.php. If I use something like $brand = $_GET["Brand"]; in mail.php it will not find "Brand". It says Undefined index: Brand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the 'name' attributes of the input fields are things like `"Brand&nbsp;1"`. To  access them more easily in PHP (as an array) you might go with `"Brand[]"`.

A `var_dump($_GET)` in mail.php would definitely be useful to debug what data is actually getting sent.

Comment: Hello, thank  you, but I can't figure it out straight away, could you give an example? You mean like $brand = $_GET["Brand&nbsp;i"]; ? Then I get Undefined index: Brand i

Comment: Oops, they actually should be `"Brand&nbsp;1"` etc. But a `var_dump` would still be very useful to you. Whether you end up making it an array or not I also suggest that the `&nbsp;` is just making things difficult.

Comment: I'm trying everything I can imagine, but still no results.

var_dump($_GET["Brand&nbsp;1"]); etc. etc. gives NULL changed the JS. and deleted &nbsp; but also no results. Maybe I can fix it tomorrow, I am pretty tired and brain dead now, it's 2 am, good night

Comment: `var_dump($_GET);` to just see *all* the data (and keys) at once.

Comment: Awesome! this looks promising. Oke so this is wat it is showing me:

`array(14) { ["Product_ID_Â 1"]=> string(9) "Â 1991001" ["Brand_Â 1"]=> string(7) "Â Razer" ["Model_Â 1"]=> string(35) "Â Mamba Elite Wireless Gaming Mouse" ["Price_Â 1"]=> string(8) "Â 129.99" ["Amount_products_Â 1"]=> string(3) "Â 1" ["Total_cost_Â 1"]=> string(8) "Â 129.99" ["name"]=> string(4) "test" ["surname"]=> string(4) "test" ["city"]=> string(4) "test" ["postalcode"]=> string(4) "test" ["phonenumber"]=> string(4) "test" ["email"]=> string(17) "klant-x@localhost" ["x"]=> string(1) "0" ["y"]=> string(1) "0" }`

Comment: Oke awesome!!!! I deleted the + &nbsp; between `name=\"Product ID " + "&nbsp;" + i +` now it looks like `name=\"Product ID " + i +` and use $_GET["Brand_1"]; and it works great now. Thanks to you! Really awesome advise and I learned another two things. Well thank you sir